# How to test non-ActiveRecord models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord

How do I test a non-ActiveRecord model class in Rails?  The code that works in the console does not seem to translate to the test suite.  Methods are not available and the whole thing just doesn't seem to work!

```
class CalendarEvent

  def test
    'Hello World'
  end

end
```

When I fire up the console, this works:

```
irb> cal_event = CalendarEvent.new
=> #<CalendarEvent:0x007fb5e3ee9fd0>
irb> cal_event.test
=> "Hello World"
```

However, when I write a test it seems the model is not loading.  None of the functions are available.

```
class CalendarEvent < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include TestApiHelperPackage

  test 'validate hello world' do
    cal_event = CalendarEvent.new
    assert_equal cal_event.test, 'Hello world'
  end
end
```

Seems like it isn't grabbing the model.  Do I have to *not* inherit from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am surprised that it even runs. You declare the class `CalendarEvent` in the test suit. Which obviously has no `test` method. Why would you name it *the exact same way* as the tested class? Just give it another name:

```
#                  ⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
class CalendarEventTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include TestApiHelperPackage

  test 'validate hello world' do
    cal_event = CalendarEvent.new
    assert_equal cal_event.test, 'Hello world'
  end
end
```

And everything should go fine. Possible you want to `require 'calender_event'` in your `test_heler.rb` as well.

Comment: Oh goodness - I feel a little silly.  Thanks.  Naming conventions in Rails/Ruby trip me up all the time.  Sigh.  I'd like to say it's just that I am tired but your quick response has saved me! Thank you!